# Python input and output threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create a python script that prints out messages from one thread, while still waiting for you to input on another. Is this possible? And if so, how?

System: Windows 7

Language: Python 2.7

I have tried this (modified from a different question):

```
import threading
import time

def message_loop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print "Hello World"

thread = threading.Thread(target = message_loop)
thread.start()

while True:
    input = raw_input("Prompt> ")
```

But what happens is: the program waits until I have finished inputting before it outputs `Hello World`.

Comment: Adding to Coffee's question, what have you read?  Did you look at the Python documentation?

Comment: I have read the documentation, and I have tried code done by others, but what happens is the code whats for me to press enter and then it outputs

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely possible. If you have a function that prints output (let's call it `print_output`) you can start it up in a different thread using the `threading` module:

```
>>> import threading
>>> my_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_output)
>>> my_thread.start()
```

You should now start getting your output. You can then run the input bit on the main thread. You could also run it in a new thread, but there are some advantages to running input in the main thread.

Comment: That just tells me how to thread, it doesn't do what I want it to though

Comment: @Pyro: I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine for me, although I'm on 2.6 rather than 2.7 and I'm not on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.
The code prints message before you input 'q'

```
import threading
import time


def run_thread():
    while True:
        print('thread running')
        time.sleep(2)
        global stop_threads
        if stop_threads:
            break


stop_threads = False
t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_thread)
t1.start()
time.sleep(0.5)

q = ''
while q != 'q':
    q = input()

stop_threads = True
t1.join()
print('finish')
```